# How to change form data during upload? - jquery-file-upload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I really need some help here please.

I'm using  jquery-file-upload to let users upload images in my website.

I need a way to change the formData after the first file be uploaded.

It starts with this value:

```
formData = {album: false};
```

And then, after the first file it creates a new ID in PHP and i need to change to the album new ID, like this:

```
formData = {album: result.new_album_ID};
```

This way the rest of the files would be stored inside the new Album.

How can i do this? I googled but didn't find any answer. Is it possible?

If you didn't understand something, please answer me before vote down.

Thank very much to you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some time i realized that is not possible. After starting the upload the formData can not be changed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Return the ID in the file upload response (your php code), and set it manually on the formData object.